# Best way to do a watch in javascript with server time synchronization

Tags: javascript, clock

I'd like to make a js watch that:

- Start time is server time (the server will supply that in the page's source code).
- Updates every second.
- (preference, not obligatory) Compatible with the latest versions of gecko, webkit, presto and IE.

I have already checked many implementations of this but I wanted to know which one is the most efficient one. That is: the one that takes less resources from the PC and the one that is more precise among all the ones that exist.

Comment: Care to share the many implementations you've checked? What's wrong with a simple `setInterval`, and if you want to be really rigorous, every few minutes (either a second interval or an internal counter) check how long has passed and synchronise.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the simple setInterval. I just wanted to know the most efficient way. I was asked to make a js script to do just that as efficient as it can be. I've already checked some at some websites using google like internet.com but I still don't know if there's, for instance, a native js way to do that (ex: Using the Date object)

Comment: It's simple enough to be efficient. That is as native a solution as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clock that ticks every second is basically animation, so one could benefit from recursive [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) ([with fallback to `setTimeout`](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/)).

```
var previousTime = 0;

function update(time) {
    if (time - previousTime >= 1000) {
        redrawClock(time);
        previousTime = time;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

With `setInterval` you'd have to create a `Date` object on each iteration, because `setInterval`'s own delay may take longer than it's formal value. See [John Resig's brilliant article on timers in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

`requestAnimationFrame` on the contrary is:

1. More efficient, optimized for the task.
2. Provides an accurate timestamp to it's callback.

Comment: You may want `previousTime = time` inside the block or you'll never redraw that clock ;)